# Bootstrap button toggle group submitting both options with form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

The following is a part of a form that is submitted created using bootstrap. The goal here is to create an option group; selecting one option should unselect (or "turn off") the other.

html:

```
<div class="col btn-group btn-group-toggle form-group" role="radiogroup" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-outline-success active"> <input id="create_option_activated" type="radio" name="create_option_activated" autocomplete="off" /> Activated </label>
    <label class="btn btn-outline-danger"> <input id="create_option_deprecated" type="radio" name="create_option_deprecated" autocomplete="off" /> Deprecated </label>
</div>
```

Messing around with the options a bit I noticed that when I click both buttons, both stay selected when I submit the form. Here is the form submission:

```json
{
  "create_option_activated": "on", 
  "create_option_deprecated": "on", 
}
```

I would like only one option to be selected.  Do I need to use javascript/jquery to achieve this or is there just something wrong with my html?

Comment: I made a reproducible example with your code. Your code works well. You may not have included the bootstrap javascript. Do you need such a result?

Comment: The issue only arises when I for example click one button, then click the other button then  submit. If you go through with one click then it works fine.

Comment: you'll have to submit the form to understand what I mean. Visually it works but the data shows the field as selected.

Comment: I understand what you are talking about. You can get two values when you submit the form. For this, the `name=""` must be the same for both inputs.

Comment: And why would you pass name="" as a unique attribute? The name="" must be lonely for radio buttons.

Comment: Hmm I see. How do I distinguish which option is selected if they have the same name? Perhaps I should be using a different component to capture?  It should operate similar to the way a <select> should.

Comment: For example, you can pass `id` as a unique attribute.

Comment: ids dont submit with the form.

Comment: I think I found a solution that yours is close to. It involves both setting the name of the inputs to be the same and then also changing the values associated with the radio button to be unique.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230606/discussion-between-josh-sharkey-and-s-kuznetsov).

Answer (score 1):

The values of the **name** attribute for a group of radio buttons must be the same. This is how radio buttons work.

But this situation can be circumvented by writing a little jquery logic that disables the label for all radio buttons except the current one.

```js
let classesSet = '.col.btn-group.btn-group-toggle.form-group';

$(classesSet + ' input[type=radio]').on("change", function () {
    $(classesSet + ' input[type=radio]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
    console.log($(this).attr('name'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col btn-group btn-group-toggle form-group" role="radiogroup" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-outline-success active"> <input id="create_option_activated" type="radio" name="create_option_activated" autocomplete="off" /> Activated </label>
    <label class="btn btn-outline-danger"> <input id="create_option_deprecated" type="radio" name="create_option_deprecated" autocomplete="off" /> Deprecated </label>
</div>
```